# Mailchimp API 3.0 - Creating Segments based on Merge Fields and Groups

Tags: mailchimp

Hi Guys I'm trying to create Segments for my Campaigns based on Merge Fields and Groups(Interests). I am using a Mailchimp Wrapper which works great for different Tasks. I'm building an associative Arrays which will be converted to a JSON-String with the Mailchimp Wrapper. I always get these errors when I am trying to create the campaign with the specific Condition Structure:

For Creating Segments based on Interests Fields (condition_type: Interests):

[image]

For Creating Segments based on Merge Fields (condition_type: TextMerge):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It was a syntax error which caused the errors in both cases.